# Save the matrix in array format after calling matrix.array()

Tags: c++, eigen3

I switched from matlab to C++ to write a CFD solver.  I am using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) linear algebra library.  It has many function for the Matrix and Vector manipulations but it's lacking in functions to convert Matrix to Array.

```
 MatrixXf m(2,2);
 m<<1,2,3,4;
 ArrayXf a(4);
 a=m.array();
```

This is the solution I have for this

```
 m.resize(4,1);
 a=m;
```

I don' like this because the `m` is changed, which I don't want because `m` is a very big matrix.

Comment: If you do `ArrayXf a(2,2); a = m.array();` it should work.

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:238: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::resize(Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Index, Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Array<float, -1, 1>; Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Index = long int]: Assertion `(!(RowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (nbRows==RowsAtCompileTime)) && (!(ColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (nbCols==ColsAtCompileTime)) && (!(RowsAtCompileTime==Dynamic

Comment: && MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) ||(nbRows<=MaxRowsAtCompileTime)) && (!(ColsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (nbCols<=MaxColsAtCompileTime)) && nbRows>=0 && nbCols>=0 && "Invalid sizes when resizing a matrix or array."' failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to copy the values you can use an `Eigen::Map` like so:

```
MatrixXf m(2,2);
m<<1,2,3,4;
Eigen::Map<ArrayXf> mp(m.data(), m.size());
```

You can then use `mp` as an `ArrayXf`. Note that this points to the original `m` matrix, *i.e.* changes to `mp` will be present in `m`. If you want a copy, you can use:

```
ArrayXf a = mp;
```

Comment: Thanks ..that is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own function and copy value by value.

```
MatrixXf matrix(2,2);
int cols=matrix.cols();
int rows=matrix.rows;
ArrayXf array(cols*rows);
for(int c=0;c<cols;c++)
    for(int r=0;r<rows;r++)
        array(c*rows+r)=matrix(c,r);
```